# How can I reroute a path with dot (.) of non-existing static file to a Razor page in ASP.NET Core Blazor Server?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

Example:

###### Background:

I have a Blazor Server App with .NET 6.

Usually static files are served normally like:

```
https://localhost/Images/img1.png
https://localhost/img2.png
```

which are located in:

```
{projectfolder}/wwwroot/Images/img1.png
{projectfolder}/wwwroot/img2.png
```

Blazor Pages (Blazor Components) like:

```
https://localhost/Counter
```

Like the template example `Counter.razor`:

```
@page "/counter"
```

I now have the requirement, that when somebody types specifically `https://localhost/foo.bar` with the **dot (.)**, which lets ASP.NET think, that its a request to a static file, which does not exists (in wwwroot), **that this should be redirected to some Blazor/Razor Page.** Ideally to a Blazor Page like `https://localhost/Counter` or also possibly simply to some Razor Page like `_Host.cshtml`.

#### In a nutshell: How to redirect:

##### `https://localhost/foo.bar?q=5` (static file request which does not exist) to `https://localhost/Counter` (Blazor)

Note that this redirect should only for the specific `https://localhost/foo.bar`, of course not for any existing static assets like `https://localhost/img.2png` and *probably* not for other non-existing assets like `https://localhost/blah.nothere`.

Note, that the normal behavior in such  a case (URL with dot, that lets the framework think a static asset has been request) is that it returns a **http 404**, which the browser renders as a blank page. I don't necessarily want to change that completely, only for one specific url with a dot, maybe for a bunch selected ones. This should also work for additional strings appended like query parameters and so forth: `https://localhost/foo.bar?q=123` `https://localhost/foo.bar/morestuff`.

###### As a secondary question:

If there is a way that this redirection would work generally for all **not-found static files**?

#### What I have tried so far

- Reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but didn't find that specific use case (yet)
- [This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17334) and [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13247), which recommends sth, that I do not understand:

> Our recommendation for now is to use the hosted template where you can configure the fallback routing.

Comment: If you want to intercept and check the original html request, use Middleware.

Comment: Perhaps you overlooked it, there is a section for [URLs with dots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#routing-with-urls-that-contain-dots) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with this:

```csharp
Action<IApplicationBuilder> handleFooBarRedirect = (IApplicationBuilder app) =>
{
    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<script>window.location.href = '/Counter';</script>");
    });
};
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/foo.bar"), handleFooBarRedirect);
```

But I'm still interested in solutions that don't require client-side JavaScript code and if it is possible with middleware like *App.Use()*. My efforts in that direction however only resulted in the fallback for Blazor (_Host) that the *App.razor* file still did use the original request path, not the updated one from the pipeline.